# How to have Query Pull Weekly Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a a query like so that ONLY shows data for the specific day.  But how can I modify this to show data for the previous 7 days? So when I run the query this week show data for the date range of 
01/24/2014 - 01/30/2014 then next week shows data for 01/31/2014 - 02/06/2014

```
SELECT * FROM SalesInformation
WHERE (datename(dw, getdate()) = 'Monday' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateSold, 101) = DATEADD   (Day,DATEDIFF(Day,0,GetDate()),0))
OR (datename(dw, getdate()) = 'Tuesday' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateSold, 101) = DATEADD(Day,DATEDIFF(Day,0,GetDate()),0))
OR (datename(dw, getdate()) = 'Wednesday' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateSold, 101) = DATEADD(Day,DATEDIFF(Day,0,GetDate()),0))
OR (datename(dw, getdate()) = 'Thursday' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateSold, 101) = DATEADD(Day,DATEDIFF(Day,0,GetDate()),0))
OR (datename(dw, getdate()) = 'Friday' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateSold, 101) = DATEADD(Day,DATEDIFF(Day,0,GetDate()),0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be seven days including time.  So 01/23/2014 10:06 AM to 1/30/2014 10:06 AM.  If you want the whole day of 01/23, cast to a DATE.

Here is a complete working example for 2012.  I changed to getdate() just in case you are using a older version of the engine.

```
-- Just playing
use tempdb;
go

-- drop existing
if object_id ('sales') > 0
drop table sales
go

-- create new
create table sales
(
  id int identity (1,1) primary key,
  sold smalldatetime,
  amt smallmoney
);
go

-- clear data
truncate table sales;
go

-- insert data
declare @dte date = '20131231';
declare @amt int;
while (@dte < '20140201')
begin
  set @amt = floor(rand(checksum(newid())) * 50000);
  set @dte = dateadd(d, 1, @dte);
  insert into sales values (@dte, @amt);
end
go

-- Show 7 * 24 hrs worth of data
select * 
from sales
where
  sold >= dateadd(d, -7, getdate()) and
  sold < getdate()
go
```

[image]

Check out Aarons Blog on dates.  It goes over the good, bad, and ugly practices.  For instance, do not use BETWEEN.

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: I get an error of SySDateTime() is not a recognized function?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx  This function was introduced in 2008.

Answer (score 2):

To get last seven day's data:

```
WHERE ... AND DATEDIFF(Day,dw,GetDate())<=7
```

Edit: To get current week's data:

```
AND dw BETWEEN(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
AND DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 6)
```

Better performance:

```
DECLARE @dw1 datetime = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)

select ... WHERE dw >= @dw1
```

For multiple weeks:

```
DECLARE @dw1 datetime = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
DECLARE @dw2 datetime = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)-7

select ... WHERE dw >= @dw1 -- current week
union all
select ... WHERE dw >= @dw2 AND dw < @dw1 -- last week
```

Comment: I modified my original post, realized I posted it incorrectly.  That query will show data for the previous 7 days as desired, but how can I have one row for 01/24/2014 - 01/30/2014 then the next row for 01/31/2014 - 02/06/2014?  And I can not hardcode dates I need it to use the GetDate() feature.

Comment: You build on this: SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0) AS StartOfWeek,DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 5) AS EndOfWeek

Comment: You're welcome, something like this: AND dw BETWEEN(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0) AND DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 6)

Comment: Be warned that if you apply a date function against a date column it becomes non SARGable (non Search Argument).  Any indexes on that column will be ignored.  Instead of asking SQL to show all records where the date difference between your column and today is 7 days or less, you should ask "show all records that are newer than 7 days ago.  It seems like semantics, but the performance difference can be staggering.

Comment: Excellent point. It would be better performance to put this Monday's date in a variable and compare with that.

Comment: @datagod - I am running the query - pasting into excel to show weekly production.  I am just not wanting to have to add date parameters each time the query is run.

Comment: @SAS - what if I added a startDateRange parameter and used that to have a individual row returned for week1 week2 week3 week4?  Is that possible? How would that query be set-up?

Comment: That would require more code than what fits in a comment filed. Perhaps Aaron's article has the solution already!

Comment: First, the datediff solution modifies the search column.  Making it a non SARGABLE argument.  Does a full table or index scan sound like fun?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write a "rolling 7 day window" query.  In this particular query, I want a 7 day window that starts at 12:00am of the first day in the range and ends at 11:59:59pm of the last day in the range.  I don't want data from today.  The date range is calculated first, then used in the where clause of my query.

```
declare @MinDate datetime,
        @MaxDate datetime

select @MinDate = convert(char(10),getdate()-7,120),
       @MaxDate = convert(char(10),getdate()-1,120) + ' 23:59:59.997'

select *
  from MyTable
 where TheDate >= @MinDate
   and TheDate <= @MaxDate
```